# Power Bi - Integrate a Report into an app - Export functionality

Tags: powerbi

When I show a Power Bi report in an iframe within my web app there's no Export functionality available. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Export of data and Print are two pieces of functionality that appear to not be supported by Embed or authenticating with Azure Active Directory.

The good thing about the PowerBI team is that they release updates to PowerBI online regularly so overnight it might just start working..

I suggest you vote on this on the ideas page so that it becomes prioritised.

Comment: Export data is now an option in the options context menu of a visual. [Print](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/classes/_src_report_.report.html#print) is also an option that can now be activated programatically. It seems that exporting as an image still doesn't exist.